# Native Script vue Sidekick complie error : AAPT: error: resource drawable/icon

Tags: android, vue.js, nativescript

I am using `nativescript` and `vue` to build a sample app. I've coded the app in [nativescript playground.](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=11ouHV&v=15)

When I preview it, it works just fine. I downloaded the app and used native script sidekick to build the android app. When creating the app it is showing an error:
 `AAPT: error: resource drawable/icon`
on researching it appears that the issue is a missing icon but I'm unable to find which directory it is that i need to place it. I would appreciate any help for it!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Place your icons in only drawable folder, do not place your icons in a specific drawable folders like drawable (v24), (v26) etc..

If you place them in specific folders, they may not be detected in some OS versions.

But placing your icons in universal `drawable` folder gives access to everything.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, i do have icons in all the drawable folders, but the build still fails. if you have the playground app you can test it by downloading the zip file in the link i posted earlier, again, thanks alot for your help

Comment: Okay, according to the error log above, that drawable thingy seems the problem.. anyway I'll get back with something else.